# Suppress listagg date truncation/conversion

Tags: oracle

Good day,

I'm doing **listagg(application_date, ', ')** where application_date is in the form dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss. The above function results in a list of dates in the form DD-MON-YY.

Any advice on how to return a date formatted like the original and not truncated/converted is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: If `application_date` is a `date`, it has no format.  If you want to concatenate the string representation of a `date`, call `to_char` on `application_date` and specify the format mask that you want.  If `application_date` has a format then it must not be a `date`, it must be a `varchar2`.  If `application_date` is a `varchar2`, you'll need to help us a bit to understand where it is being cast and manipulated.

Comment: Thanks Justin for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like Oracle's implicit type conversion has kicked in. The `LISTAGG` function expects VARCHAR2, your `application_date` is probably a DATE, so Oracle converts the DATE to a VARCHAR. As you didn't specify a date format, Oracle uses the default date format.

You can avoid this by doing the conversion yourself:

```
listagg(to_char(application_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS'), ',')
```